# jQGrid cell editing and inline edit Conflict

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new in Stackoverflow and want to ask my first question, please help and thanks in advance.

I want using two jQGrid editing function together that is **Inline Edit** and **Cell Editing** is it possible? I was try this on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/513/) and found something error. What is it? If I click cell jQGrid Cell Editing works fine for me, but if click another cell the first cell I clicked not restore. as like in jQGrid Documentation :

> "..The cell is saved when we press [Enter] again, when we press [Tab], or when we click on another cell.."

- When I press [Enter] -> cell restore and saved! works
- When I press [Tab]   -> cell restore and saved! works
- When I click another cell -> cell not restore and not saved!

Note:

> before i put Inline Edit function all works fine, but after I adding this two line of code the error above happened.

```
$("#grid").navGrid("#pager",{edit:false,add:false,del:true});
$("#grid").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#pager");
```

my jsfiddle - > http://jsfiddle.net/CzVVK/513/

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why the hell you even need both of them ?
2. By error you mean smth like this ? >

   input type="text" id="3_name" name="name" role="textbox" style="width: 98%;"

Comment: Yes. I need both of them because my client need feature that can make him easy to edit and move between cell -> **Cell Editing** . Then my client need also feature that can insert new data directly on the grid  -> **Inline Edit**